# body background image loop

Tags: jquery, loops

I am trying to get the body background image to swap out and loop through. The current code I have written does the effect but because of how its written it fades out and in all the content on the document also. I cant quit wrap my head on how to change it so I can get the content to not fade out and just stay but still have the background image loop. Any one able to help? Thanks! Here is the code:

```
var currentBackground = 0;
var backgrounds = [];
backgrounds[0] = 'images/clubhouseview.jpg';
backgrounds[1] = 'images/holefour.jpg';

function changeBackground() {
    currentBackground++;
    if(currentBackground > 1) currentBackground = 0;

    $('body').fadeOut(100,function() {
        $('body').css({
            'background-image' : "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
        });
        $('body').fadeIn(100);
    });


    setTimeout(changeBackground, 2000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(changeBackground, 2000);        
});
```

Comment: You mean change background image without Fadein/out animation

Comment: I just created Fiddle for Your problem.http://jsfiddle.net/dZK2V/ .Please tell what is expected by u.

Comment: No, the background image can fade in and out. But because the jquery selector is selecting $('body') everything in the html document in the body is also being faded out and back in along with the image. I dont want the content to fade out, just the background to fade out and loop through a set of images

Comment: @PratikJoshi here is an update to your fiddle. As you can see the content on the page also fades out and in. I just want the content to stay without fading out http://jsfiddle.net/dZK2V/1/

Comment: did solution by Guy sorted ur problem out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is you are applying `.fadeOut()` to the `body` element. For this to work you need to apply the effect to the element that is changing.

I would use the JS to change the image url and then use css to do the transitions. E.g

```
body {
-webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

[Demo here](http://codepen.io/guyfedwards/pen/BxDHb)

This will add a transition only to the background-image so only that will be animated, not the rest of the body content.

Comment: Thank you! That worked out great!Is there a way for me to have js set the images as this css rule also body{background-image: url('') no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover;} for each image?

Comment: You could just set the `background-repeat: no-repeat;` etc in the css for the body element?